# read tow Column txt file in specific directory and import to matlab

Tags: matlab

I have two Column txt file every Column contain the speed on dc motor. I want to plot every Column with the time and compaire the two curves.
I tried this code, but not working:

```
fid = fopen('C:\Users\Hussam Yonis\Desktop\recive.txt','r');
KK = fscanf(fid,'%f %f',[2,50]);
t=0:0.05:0.05*length(a(:,1))-0.05;
plot(t,fid(:,1),'b',t,fid(:,2),'r')
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This will improve your odds of getting an answer.

Comment: What's the content of your `receive.txt` ? What error did you get?

Comment: the content is double numbers matrix the error is "??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions."

Answer (score 0):

`fid` is just a pointer corresponding to the opened file and does not have several dimensions, so `fid(:,2)` will give a matrix dimensions exceeded error. You want to plot the data that came out of the file, `KK` in your case. Try this:

```
plot(t,KK(:,1),'b',t,KK(:,2),'r')
```

I also suspect you might have your indexing the wrong way round, although as your code is not minimal, complete and verifiable, it is difficult to say. You might find you need the following command:

```
plot(t,KK(1,:),'b',t,KK(2,:),'r')
```